# Automapper map int property values from List<type> to List<int>

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to map an int property from a list of objects to a `List<int>`.
Here is what my class structure looks like:

I have a parent class:

```
public class Parent
{
    ...
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

Location class:

```
public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Destination class for mapping:

```
public class Destination
{
    ...
    public List<int> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code I am trying to use to accomplish the mapping between `List<Location>` to `List<int>`:

```
CreateMap<Parent, Destination>()
.ForMember(d => d.Locations, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Locations.Select(l => l.LocationId)))
```

This isn't working. I get the following error:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Unable to create a map expression from **Location.LocationId
>       (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])** to **Destination.Locations (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32])**

Any idea what I'm not doing right?

Comment: Have you tried .ToList() on the end of your select?

Comment: Good idea. I tried this and it appears to have handled it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the exception says:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Unable to create a map expression from Location.LocationId (System.Collections.Generic.**IEnumerable**1[System.Int32]) to Destination.Locations (System.Collections.Generic.**List**1[System.Int32])

I believe that this happens because you are attempting to map an IEnumerable to a List.
You either add a `ToList()` to the map expression after the `Select`. (not recommended)
Or declare the `Locations` property as an `IEnumerable<int>` in your Destination class.

Comment: This is what JamesT suggested in the comments above. This solved me problem. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out that I also had to add a mapping for Location to int as Chris Pickford suggests below. That plus the .ToList() solved my problem.

Answer (score 8):

You need to alter your AutoMapper configuration to map between `Location` and `int` then it takes care of the rest for you:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Location, int>().ConvertUsing(source => source.LocationId);
cfg.CreateMap<Parent, Destination>().ForMember(dest => dest.Locations, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Locations));
```

See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/chrispickford/a1dd920fe4aae379847140cdda6d6cd4) for working example.

Comment: @downvoter - Care to explain how this answer is incorrect or can be improved?

Comment: Not sure why you got a down vote. I had to use your first line of code to get the correct answer.